# how to use .net view in queue explorer

Tags: c#, nservicebus, msmq

Our company uses Queue Explorer 4.0 pro by cogin and I've been searching all over their website and the only thing I can find on using their .net view is this little blurp about viewing a message being parsed with a .net assembly: [blog post](https://www.cogin.com/blog/queueexplorer/queueexplorer-1-1-released-net-view-remote-sending-message-body-operations/)

so for instance, the body of my message is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<CreateAuditLogEntry xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.net/Phone.Messages">
    <SurveyId>12345</SurveyId>
    <AuditEventId>704</AuditEventId>
    <EventDateTime>2018-06-08T13:21:07.6647304Z</EventDateTime>
</CreateAuditLogEntry>
```

and I've tried using the assembly that we tell NServicebus to use that sends said message.It didn't have the `SerializableAttribute` so I figured I'd just make my own assembly with the same namespace and try to add all the same things:

```
namespace Phone.Messages
{
    [System.Serializable]
    public class CreateAuditLogEntry
    {
        public long SurveyId { get; set; }
        public int AuditEventId { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime EventDateTime { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I compile that and point Queue Explorer to it and it tells me that it still can't deserialize the object: `Error: Cannot deserialize the message passed as an argument. Cannot recognize the serialization format.` Has anyone used this and made it work successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That xmlns part seems to be the problem here. Your sample works when that namespace is specified through XmlRoot attribute:

```
[XmlRoot(Namespace="http://tempuri.net/Phone.Messages")]
public class CreateAuditLogEntry
{
    public long SurveyId { get; set; }
    public int AuditEventId { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime EventDateTime { get; set; }
}
```

Btw. QueueExplorer dynamically loads assemblies specified for .Net views, you don't have to restart it if you rebuild and create new dll/exe.

Comment: the xmlroot was the trick. Put that in and compiled like you said and it worked. Not very impressed though. :/ All that messing around for an underwhelming experience. Oh well. At least I know how to do it now. Thank you.